# orientdb search by traversing through fields

Tags: database, select, orientdb

**The problem is basically searching inside a multi-level embedded ODocument.** Let me explain,

I have three orientDB classes - Feedback, File, and FileContent.

Feedback ODocument has an embedded field reference to File ODocument, and File has an embedded reference to FileContent.

FileContent has a field 'content' that basically has text for the file where I want to search.

**Use Case:** Write a select query on Feedback class so that it gives me all Feedback ODocuments that have the search keyword.
That is,
If I want to search for the keyword 'progress' in the file content, and fetch all feedbacks that have this keyword, the sql would look like:

**select * from Feedback where any() like '%progress%'**

But this query doesn't search through file content.
Any help is appreciated.

Here is an example sequence of events to achieve the current state:

```
orientdb {db=mydb}> create class Feedback;
orientdb {db=mydb}> create class File;
orientdb {db=mydb}> create class FileContent;
orientdb {db=mydb}> insert into FileContent (a,b) values ('Lebron James','is the King.')
orientdb {db=mydb}> select from FileContent

----+-----+------------+------------
#   |@RID |a           |b
----+-----+------------+------------
0   |#29:0|Lebron James|is the King.
----+-----+------------+------------

orientdb {db=mydb}> insert into File (c,d) values (#29:0, 'Steph Curry too!');
orientdb {db=mydb}> select from File

----+-----+-----+----------------
#   |@RID |c    |d
----+-----+-----+----------------
0   |#27:0|#29:0|Steph Curry too!
----+-----+-----+----------------

orientdb {db=mydb}> insert into Feedback (e,f) values (#27:0, 'The MVP is here.');
orientdb {db=mydb}> select from Feedback

----+-----+-----+----------------
#   |@RID |e    |f
----+-----+-----+----------------
0   |#28:0|#27:0|The MVP is here.
----+-----+-----+----------------

orientdb {db=mydb}> select from File where any() like '%Lebron%';

----+-----+-----+----------------
#   |@RID |c    |d
----+-----+-----+----------------
0   |#27:0|#29:0|Steph Curry too!
----+-----+-----+----------------

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.001 sec(s).
orientdb {db=mydb}> select from Feedback where any() like '%Lebron%';

0 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.001 sec(s).

// I want the last query to return the Feedback row. Is it possible?
// Also, I am not declaring the property as embedded here because then I have to do {"@type":"d", ...}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sequence of commands to achieve your current state? I mean, how you're embedding the fields.

Comment: @vitorenesduarte I just posted the example. It is close to what I am doing using the Document API.

Comment: You're not embedding records. Embedded documents don't own a Record ID. I believe if you embed them for real you'll achieve what you want

Comment: @vitorenesduarte Then why does search in one level of indirection (the second last query in my example) work?

Comment: I noticed that. I don't know details, but maybe that's how 'any()' works: it only searches one depth level (this is pure conjecture ^^)

Comment: how is it going? [This](https://gist.github.com/vitorenesduarte/39d90c216312c87ef95d) is what I meant.

Comment: @vitorenesduarte Sorry for replying so late. Many thanks for posting the example. :) So, does multi-level search work in your example?

Comment: Yes, it does (only tried two-depth level, but I assume it will work for any depth level).

Comment: Hi @vitorenesduarte, can you please have a look at this question? You are the only active orientdb user i know of. Thanks in advance! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465430/database-schema-is-different-exception-in-orientdb-baasbox

Comment: Hey @K.K. I'm not working with OrientDB right now, but I can take a look. The link is invalid.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385573/database-schema-is-different-exception-in-orientdb-baasbox. I think the issue is with using their ODocument Java api.

Answer (score 0):

Use traverse statement.. it will solve your problem.. but you can't get the feedback coz you have to use embedded..

```
List<ODocument> result = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>("TRAVERSE * FROM File where any() like '%Lebron%'"));

if (result != null && result.size() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println(result.get(i).field("rid"));
    }
}
```

this will return File and FileContent class...