# Database schema is different - Exception in OrientDB - Baasbox

Tags: orientdb, baasbox

I am getting the following exception on starting up baasbox (it has embedded orientdb).

This exception happens when I connect to the database using console.sh/connect:plocal and then run a few select queries, but doesn't happen the first time I startup baasbox.

Any help is appreciated. 
Orientdb version: 1.7.10

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Database schema is different. Please export your old database with the previous version of OrientDB and reimport it using the current one.
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.fromStream(OSchemaShared.java:800) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.10.jar:1.7.10]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.type.ODocumentWrapperNoClass.reload(ODocumentWrapperNoClass.java:70) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.10.jar:1.7.10]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.load(OSchemaShared.java:921) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.10.jar:1.7.10]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault$1.call(OMetadataDefault.java:115) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.10.jar:1.7.10]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault$1.call(OMetadataDefault.java:110) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.10.jar:1.7.10]
  at com.orientechnologies.common.concur.resource.OSharedContainerImpl.getResource(OSharedContainerImpl.java:53) ~[orient-commons-1.7.10.jar:1.7.10]
Wrapped by: com.orientechnologies.common.exception.OException: Error on creation of shared resource
  at com.orientechnologies.common.concur.resource.OSharedContainerImpl.getResource(OSharedContainerImpl.java:55) ~[orient-commons-1.7.10.jar:1.7.10]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault.init(OMetadataDefault.java:110) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.10.jar:1.7.10]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault.load(OMetadataDefault.java:68) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.10.jar:1.7.10]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.open(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:291) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.10.jar:1.7.10]
  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:49) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.10.jar:1.7.10]
  at com.baasbox.db.DbHelper.open(DbHelper.java:353) ~[classes/:na]
  at com.baasbox.Global.onStart(Global.java:169) ~[classes/:na]
  at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.onStart(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:18) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
  at play.api.GlobalPlugin.onStart(GlobalSettings.scala:203) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
  at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
  at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318) [scala-library.jar:na]
  at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
  at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
  at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
  at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
  at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
  at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:139) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
  at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
  at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
  at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
  at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200) [scala-library.jar:na]
  at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
  at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:102) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [scala-library.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [scala-library.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361) [scala-library.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library.jar:na]
  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library.jar:na]
```

Comment: When you said "but does not happen the first time I startup baasbox" that means only sometimes you get the exception? 
Just installed baasbox and after the first insert and query data, it works correctly or already at this stage you've got problems?

Answer (score 0):

I got this reply from the baasbox team:

`When you use console.sh (the OrientDB console tool), be sure the BaasBox is not running, otherwise you can have data corruption.
However now it is clear that the error occurs after you have accessed the db via the console using a different version of the ODB tool.`

I was using a different version of Orientdb tool (console.sh v2.0) than the orientdb version 1.7.10 used in baasbox. This caused the corruption and may have messed up the DB schema.